Right-pad a series of lines to give them common length n
I often find myself wanting to take a number of consecutive lines with different lengths, and right-pad them with space so they have the same length, say n. What's a good way to do this painlessly?
If I could select the (yet non-existent) rectangle I wanted and use something like open-rectangle, that would be nice, but that doesn't work.

What do you want to happen if n is smaller than the length of the longest line? Should longer lines be truncated? Or left alone (while every shorter line is padded)?  Or should the function signal an error?

@NickD Good question, I didn't think of that. I think any of those are acceptable, maybe leave them alone

Does the answer below answer your question? Please provide feedback - do not leave the question orphaned.


M-x cua-rectangle-mark-mode to start marking a rectangle
Extend the right edge of the rectangle to where you want the padding to end
M-P to introduce the padding
C-<return> to exit the rectangle mode

See "CUA rectangle support" in M-x finder-commentary RET cua-base for more information.
You might find it convenient to bind C-<return> to cua-rectangle-mark-mode in the global keymap, so that you can use the same key sequence to enter and exit that mode.  (Or, if you happen to be using cua-selection-mode (or even cua-mode), that'll already be a default binding for you.)

You can mostly do this using string-rectangle with the two corners of the rectangle being the top and bottom of the right-hand edge (and you might use rectangle-mark-mode to more-conveniently establish those two positions).  However string-rectangle treats empty input as a request to re-use the most-recent string, and consequently I don't think you can make it use an empty string unless string-rectangle-history is nil, which means there's an edge-case problem if you didn't want to add any additional padding to the longest line in that rectangle, but rather just wanted to pad all the other lines to the exact same length.  In the absence of any string-rectangle-history though, that approach (and just typing RET at the prompt) works fine too.
